# How do I delete model objects based on foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Post model and a Vote model. The vote model keeps track of the upvotes and downvotes in a column called polarity. I want to make it so deleting a post will also delete all its associates votes. How can I accomplish this?

**Schema:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dependent` in your association.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html